# Unable to focus on the number plate of a truck image, and retrieve it in order to put in a different folder

Tags: python, opencv

[image: sample input][image: sample input[![sample output )the green part should actually focus and outline on the number plate)]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzPPK.png)

**Kindly ignore that the images of input and output trucks are different. In reality, the output should be the focused number plate of the input image (the entire truck).** 
I have been trying to detect nameplates from a truck image. I followed instructions from a website, but I am unable to focus on the number plate alone and retrieve it. In the end, I am getting green lines at random places on the truck image. The website tells me to convert the original image into grey scale and many more after which it is supposed to detect the number plate, but it is not happening.
I am new to open CV and just following what a website suggested me to. My goal is to retrieve only the number-plate from the truck image and put it into a different folder. 
Suggestions on where I can understand these things would be helpful.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = 
cv2.imread("path")
cv2.namedWindow("Original Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Original Image",img)
# Display image

# RGB to Gray scale conversion
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
cv2.namedWindow("Gray Converted Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Gray Converted Image",img_gray)
# Display Image

# Noise removal with iterative bilateral filter(removes noise while preserving edges)
noise_removal = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_gray,9,75,75)
cv2.namedWindow("Noise Removed Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Noise Removed Image",noise_removal)
# Display Image

# Histogram equalisation for better results
equal_histogram = cv2.equalizeHist(noise_removal)
cv2.namedWindow("After Histogram equalisation",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("After Histogram equalisation",equal_histogram)
# Display Image

# Morphological opening with a rectangular structure element
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
morph_image = cv2.morphologyEx(equal_histogram,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel,iterations=15)
cv2.namedWindow("Morphological opening",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Morphological opening",morph_image)
# Display Image

# Image subtraction(Subtracting the Morphed image from the histogram equalised Image)
sub_morp_image = cv2.subtract(equal_histogram,morph_image)
cv2.namedWindow("Subtraction image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Subtraction image", sub_morp_image)
# Display Image

# Thresholding the image
ret,thresh_image = cv2.threshold(sub_morp_image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.namedWindow("Image after Thresholding",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Image after Thresholding",thresh_image)
# Display Image

# Applying Canny Edge detection
canny_image = cv2.Canny(thresh_image,250,255)
cv2.namedWindow("Image after applying Canny",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Image after applying Canny",canny_image)
# Display Image
canny_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(canny_image)

# dilation to strengthen the edges
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
# Creating the kernel for dilation
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(canny_image,kernel,iterations=1)
cv2.namedWindow("Dilation", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Dilation", dilated_image)
# Displaying Image

# Finding Contours in the image based on edges
new,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours= sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
# Sort the contours based on area ,so that the number plate will be in top 10 contours
screenCnt = None
# loop over our contours
for c in contours:
 # approximate the contour
 peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
 approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.06 * peri, True)  # Approximating with 6% error
 # if our approximated contour has four points, then
 # we can assume that we have found our screen
 if len(approx) == 4:  # Select the contour with 4 corners
  screenCnt = approx
  break
final = cv2.drawContours(img, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
# Drawing the selected contour on the original image
cv2.namedWindow("Image with Selected Contour",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Image with Selected Contour",final)

# Masking the part other than the number plate
mask = np.zeros(img_gray.shape,np.uint8)
new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask,[screenCnt],0,255,-1,)
new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
cv2.namedWindow("Final_image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Final_image",new_image)

# Histogram equal for enhancing the number plate for further processing
y,cr,cb = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(new_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb))
# Converting the image to YCrCb model and splitting the 3 channels
y = cv2.equalizeHist(y)
# Applying histogram equalisation
final_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.merge([y,cr,cb]),cv2.COLOR_YCrCb2RGB)
# Merging the 3 channels
cv2.namedWindow("Enhanced Number Plate",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# Creating a Named window to display image
cv2.imshow("Enhanced Number Plate",final_image)
# Display image
cv2.waitKey() # Wait for a keystroke from the user
```

Comment: You have 3 images called final_image. What is the line that has a different output than expected?

Comment: @JonathanR thanks for the reply. The final_image at the last line of the code, with "Enhanced Number Plate" is the one that is of concern. I just want the final output to show the number plate, not the original image.

Comment: Do all other image output the correct result?

Comment: @JonathanR No, they are all showing proper types of images (like grayscale, morphed, etc), but I want it all to happen on the cropped out numberplate and not on the original image

Comment: Is `screenCnt` supposed to be the bounding box of the license plate? You should explain more what you are trying to do and where it goes wrong, else helping you will be hard.

Comment: @JonathanR yes it behaves like an outline for the license plate

Comment: @JonathanR, should I place this code in the beginning?

Comment: Can you post some source image(s) and the output you obtained ? Thanks

Comment: @Link I have edited my question. It shows the sample input and the output I am getting. But i need my code to show the green outline for the numberplate.

Answer (score 1):

`l_plate_img = img[screenCnt[0]:screenCnt[1], screenCnt[2]:screenCnt[3]`

should return just the part of your image containing the license plate, all further processing can be done on this object.